# Is there a way to return to a line of code? java

Tags: java, arrays, restart

I'm creating a gambling program. I completed the betting process, however I'd like to make it so that the gambler can continue betting after the bet is over, but how do I restart the code and allow the user to replace their bet?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Casino {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    int colmax = 2;
    double balance = 2500.0;
    double prize = 0;
    double bet1 = 0;
    double bet2 = 0;
    System.out.println("          -==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-"          );
    System.out.println("-==-==-=={ Welcome to the Marist Casino! }==-==-==-");
    System.out.println("          -==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-"          );

    System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
    System.out.println("(2) Blackjack");
    System.out.println("(3) Crash");
    System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
    int game = input.nextInt();

    if(game == 1) {
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Red Fox Roullete!");
    System.out.print("Please choose Black or Red....and a number from 1-10: ");
    String color = input.next();
    int number = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on "+color+ "?: ");
    bet1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on "+number+"?: ");
    bet2 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("------------------Results--------------------");
    System.out.println("You just bet "+bet1+" on "+color+" and "+bet2+" on "+number);
    System.out.println("Spinning............");
    Random rouletteNum = new Random();
    int rNum = min + rouletteNum.nextInt(max);
    int rCol = min + rouletteNum.nextInt(colmax);
    if (rCol == 1) {
        System.out.println("The machine landed on Black "+rNum);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The machine landed on Red "+rNum);
    }
    if(rNum == number) {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you guessed the right number!");
            balance += bet2 * 5;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry!You didnt guess the right number! You've lost "+bet2);
            balance -= bet2;
    }
    if(rCol == 1 && color == "black") {
        System.out.print("Congrats, you guessed the right color!");
            balance += bet1 * 2;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry!You didnt guess the right color!You've lost "+bet1);
            balance -= bet1;
    }
    System.out.print("New balance is :"+balance);
    }
  }
}
```

So to conclude, the balance is printed in the final line, and I want to ask, `"Do you want to place another bet?"`but I'm not sure how I'd get back up to the code that allows them to do that. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: You mean a loop? Google that term, it's fundamental in programming.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Use functions. Split the code into separate responsibilities. Or use basic and call `goto 140`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method that handles the betting activity and call the method after the balance is displayed.

```
public static void bet() { 

  System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on "+color+ "?: ");
  bet1 = input.nextInt();
  System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on "+number+"?: ");
  bet2 = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("------------------Results--------------------");
  System.out.println("You just bet "+bet1+" on "+color+" and "+bet2+" on 
  "+number);
  System.out.println("Spinning............");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a infinitive loop with a proper break like:

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
    System.out.println("(2) Blackjack");
    System.out.println("(3) Crash");
    System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
    int game = input.nextInt();

    if(game == 1) { ... }
    ..
    else if (game == -1) //end users writes -1 to quit the loop
      {break;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `do ... while` statements. 
Example you could do:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean anotherBet; 
do {
    ... // place all your code here
    ...
    ...
    // Check if the user wants to bet again! after first game is over.
    System.out.print("Do you want to place another bet? (true/false): ");
    anotherBet = input.nextBoolean();
} while(anotherBet);
```

Hope this helps